# How to output all solutions for Goal from non-interactive script

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a Node.JS application that I want to do the following with:
 1. Queries an API to read clauses and writes them to a file `data.pro`
 2. Runs `swipl` as a command to output the result
 3. Parses the result and continues the Node.JS execution.

I already have the `swipl` command as:

```
swipl -s triangular.pro -g "customRatio(A,C,D,1.05,T)." -t halt.
```

Now `customRatio/5` has a ton of solutions that I would like to process further in my main application. An example output of running this in interactive mode would be:

```
A =  (portugal, brazil, 656.1249261859458),
B =  (brazil, germany, 5.36135535063264),
C =  (germany, portugal, 0.0002993),
T = 1.0528532618885567 ;
```

I don't need it to be in this format, I just want the most straightforward way to get all the goals from adding something either to the command or my program. I've seen examples with `findAll` but couldn't get it to work with multiple outputs to the stream. I've also seen examples with `dump` and `write`.

I'm just thinking there must be a trivial way to just dump all the results to a file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3). Also checkout the [Finding all solutions to a goal](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions) chapter.

Comment: My issue with the OP is that I have 4 variables to find, and they're not independent. findall/3 takes the first argument as the goal. So if I did `findall(P1,customRatio(P1,P2,P3, 1.03, Ratio), LIST).`, I'm only getting the solutions for P1. But I want the P1,P2,P3,Ratio set, same as described in the example. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: I guess I can instead of P1 have `(P1,P2,P3,Ratio)`, thank you. How about printing this to a file? I can just open and write a stream. Thanks @DmitriChubarov. Let me try that.

Answer (score 3):

Could your please elaborate, which problems did you encounter with `forall`?

The `forall/2` based solution I can think is as follows (I've split it to multiple lines so it's more readable):

```
forall(
    (Goal = customRatio(A, C, D, 1.05, T), call(Goal)),
    (write(Goal), nl)
)
```

The command becomes:

```
swipl -s triangular.pro -g "forall((Goal = customRatio(A, C, D, 1.05, T), call(Goal)), (write(Goal), nl))." -t halt.
```

PS: you can put `forall` into helper predicate which takes `Goal` as an argument and then writes all results to screen or file, e.g.:

```
swipl -s triangular.pro -g "results_to_file(customRatio(A, C, D, 1.05, T))." -t halt.
```

Comment: It's been a while (years) since I've touched Prolog so I didn't get at first that the Goal didn't need to be a single variable and can be a composite one. You've also addressed the writing to file so I'm going to test that out immediately. Cheers, and upvoted.

Comment: oh, by way I didn't mean `forall` but `findall`. Typo on the OP that I corrected.

Comment: So far, got there with the first help from the comments:
```findOpportunities(MinRatio):-
  open('output.txt',write, Stream),
  findall((P1,P2,P3,Ratio),customRatio(P1,P2,P3, MinRatio, Ratio), List),
  write(Stream, List),
  close(Stream). Will try with `forall` now.
```

Comment: Your way @code_x386 outputs the clause itself, with the function name. I've found the previous solution on the comments a bit better, but yours helped me get there. I'll post both in a separate answer with example outputs in a second.

Answer (score 1):

So with the help of the comments from @DmitriChubarov and a similar reply from @code_x386 I got there.

Assuming we have a function that already provides the results:

```
customRatio(A,C,D,1.05,T)
```

We want all results for the Goal and write them to a file. I've done that using:

```
findOpportunities(MinRatio):-
  open('output.txt',write, Stream),
  findall((P1,P2,P3,Ratio),customRatio(P1,P2,P3, MinRatio, Ratio), List),
  write(Stream, List),
  close(Stream).
```

And then calling the following on the command line:

```
swipl -s triangular.pro -g "findOpportunities(1.02)." -t halt.
```

The solution proposed by code_x386 works but writes the clause as well as the results, for example:

```
customRatio((portugal,brazil,1707.3295658260913),(brazil,germany,0.03409),(germany,portugal,0.017399),1,1.0126716463779004)
customRatio((brazil,germany,0.03409),(germany,france,0.001601),(france,brazil,18663.68047779022),1,1.018628032848078)
customRatio((brazil,germany,0.03409),(germany,portugal,0.017399),(portugal,brazil,1707.3295658260913),1,1.0126716463779004)
```

Thank you both!